# Java Regex capture Multiple Groups in code

Tags: java, regex

I need to parse multiple if and else if entries in machine generated code to extract eventName values.  All I care about is an infinite amount of combinations of whats contained in quotes in my string below.

Consider the following code:

```
  String input = "if (eventName== \"event1\") {//blahblah\n}\nelse if (eventName==\"event2\") {//blahblah\n   }";       
  String strPattern = "eventName(?s)==.*\"(.*)\"";          
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(strPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

  Matcher match = pattern.matcher(input);               

  while (match.find()) {
        System.out.printf("group: %s%n", match.group(1));
  }
```

This only gives me the second captured group event2.  How can I achieve parsing the above with all the combinations of whitespace and line feeds that could be in between  eventName==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try non-greedy way

```
String strPattern = "eventName(?s)==.*?\"(.*?)\"";
```

Or

```
String strPattern = "eventName==\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"";
```

output:

```
group: event1
group: event2
```

Second Regex Pattern Explanation:

```
  eventName==              'eventName=='
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times)
  "                        '"'
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more times)
  )                        end of \1
  "                        '"'
```